# Changing DOM on React page from Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am converting an existing site from jQuery, etc to a React site. I also have a Chrome Extension that works specifically for this site, so I have access to both sides of this. The issue I'm having is that the Chrome Extension will not update the DOM on the React site, and that's essential for it to function.

The original site worked properly with this in the Chrome Extension:

```
var tab = yield browser.createTab('localhost:3000/dashboard', this.window);
console.log('Delay 3000');
yield this.delay(3000, 3000);
var showProRunning = yield browser.runCodeOnTab(tab, `$('#isProRunning').val('yes')`);
```

The React Site does not work with this:

```
var tab = yield browser.createTab('localhost:3000/dashboard', this.window);
console.log('Delay 3000');
yield this.delay(3000, 3000);
var showProRunning = yield browser.runCodeOnTab(tab, `document.getElementById('isProRunning').value='yes'`);
```

The three second delay is there as a temporary hack to make sure all of the DOM is loaded before the extension tries to do anything with it. I would expect the Chrome Extension to be able to access the hidden input field 'isProRunning' and update its value, but this does not happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

--EDIT--
Based on wOxxOm's comment I got it working this way:

```
yield browser.runCodeOnTab(tab, `document.getElementById('isProRunning').focus()`);
yield browser.runCodeOnTab(tab, `document.execCommand('insertText', false, '1')`);
```

Rather than using a hidden input I had to use a text input, and hide it in a div with height and width of 0. Trying to update a hidden input didn't work.

Comment: 1) dispatch a bubbling `'change'` event to the element or 2) focus it and use document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'yes')

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So far I can't get either option to work, although I'm not sure I completely understand them...